# Unable to connect to the Internet via LAN despite the connection showing as established

Tags: 11.10, networking, lan

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10. I am facing a problem connecting via LAN. We have a firewalled network. After entering static IP, gateway, DNS, etc., it shows connection as established but we are unable to use the Internet using the wired connection (LAN).

While checking system testing following error shows under network test:

```
ERROR:root:Could not find def gateway info in /proc 
ERROR:root:Could not find default gateway by running route
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Regards,

Answer (score 3):

Since you decline to say what you have as far as hardware it would be a WAG answer. Therefore here goes.

Your NIC has the wrong drivers installed. Consult one of these links provided

[Networking Tutorial](http://www.debianadmin.com/ubuntu-networking-for-basic-and-advanced-users.html)

[Network Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager0.7)

[Ubuntu Wireless](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper)

[How to install Ethernet Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113794/how-do-i-install-the-ethernet-drivers-in-ubuntu-10-04)